# How to use images as Sprites in Visual Studio 2010 C++?

Tags: c++, sprites, sfml, visual-studio

So i'm trying to create my first videogame, a simple code of "Space Invaders" for a project at school and I'm always getting stuck at images. I'm using C++ to code and I've tried both SFML and Magick++ as libraries but i just can't set them up properly it seems. Can someone help me through setting up either one of them or even another method?

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example what you're trying so far, and detail what's not working? (eg. do you get a particular compiler or runtime error?) It's usually easier to spot & correct a mistake than to give a complete guide from the ground up (which would probably rehash a lot of what you already know)

Comment: yeah, sure! Sorry, it's my first post here so I'm not really familiar with the format. The error messages when i try to use Magick say "no such file or directory `#incude <Magick++.`. I just followed the instructions in the pdf for Magick++ and i don't know ho to properly set it up apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if the text you pasted in your comment was copied verbatim, you have a typo. Should be `#include <Magick...` not `#incude`.

If that's just a typo here, then you may have a configuration error when adding Magick++ to your solution. For VisualStudio you'll want to add the directory containing .h files in project properties -> VC++ directories -> include directories and make sure the .dlls are in your working directory.

Having said that, I'm not sure ImageMagick is what you're looking for. It will sort out any loading and processing of images, but not displaying it in the game window (as far as I know). You may be better off using SDL. It has a pretty gentle learning curve and will certainly allow you to easily load images and display sprites in your game window. You can get SDL and look at the documentation [on the SDL website](https://www.libsdl.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! And yeah, it was a typo, that was not the main problem. I'll look into SDL for now